# Processing load and play sound

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to load different sounds for my game. One sound has to play overtime the play jumps, called "upNoise." I want to have a class called "Sound" and call different functions to play different files. The problem says: It says the constructor "SoundFile(Sound, String)" does not exist. Heres my code.

```
import processing.sound.*;

class Sound {

  SoundFile file;

  Sound() {

    file = new SoundFile(this, "upNoise.wav");

  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SoundFile` constructor expects an instance of `PApplet` passed into its constructor.

When you're in a sketch, you can use the `this` keyword to refer to that `PApplet` instance.

But since you're in a `Sound` class, your `this` keyword is referring to the `Sound` instance. That's what you're passing into the `SoundFile` constructor. And `SoundFile` doesn't know what your `Sound` class is, so you get that error.

To fix this, you have to pass the `PApplet` instance into the `SoundFile` constructor.

**Option 1:** Pass the `PApplet` instance into your `Sound` constructor as a parameter, and then pass that parameter into the `SoundFile` constructor. Your `Sound` constructor might look like this:

```
Sound(PApplet sketch){
   file = new SoundFile(sketch, "upNoise.wav");
}
```

Then in your Processing sketch, you'd pass the `PApplet` into your `Sound` constructor using the `this` keyword:

```
void setup(){
   Sound yourSound = new Sound(this);
}
```

**Option 2:** Since Processing treats all classes as inner classes, you could also use the slightly strange syntax of referring to the "outer this" by using the name of your sketch instead of passing in the `this` from your sketch:

```
Sound(){
   file = new SoundFile(YourSketchName.this, "upNoise.wav");
}
```

But this is a little weird and won't work in all cases, so you're probably better off just passing `this` in from your sketch.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/this.html).